# How to add dashed lines parallel to axis lines in scatterplot 3D

Tags: r, plot, 3d, scatter-plot

I am trying to add dashed lines parallel to x,y,z axises in scatter plot 3D. Can I can modify following code to add dashed lines:

```
energy <- c(274.7539889,178.8493447,206.8084623,225.2049707,234.91386,359.9859873,251.4635995,406.480808,321.8857666,250.3560571)

time <- c(25.93572586,16.8826942,19.52192798,21.25848803,22.17497005,33.98130057,23.73720217,38.37023385,30.38478544,23.6326544)

cost <- c(6.861252677,13.22453603,13.53984311,4.355987685,21.9010971,16.41429768,15.33270222,27.78572681,26.44744434,24.62564853)



library(scatterplot3d)

with(mtcars, {scatterplot3d(
                 energy,time,cost,
                 log="xyz", zlab="Cost", ylab="Time", xlab="Energy",
                 cex.lab=1.5,font.lab=2,lwd=3,pch=20,
                 highlight.3d = T, angle = 55
)})
```

Comment: Why is that code inside a `with(mtcars)` expression?

Comment: Where exactly do you want these dashed lines? At a guess, somewhere on the xy plane at minimum z to the same point on the xy plane at maximum z?

Comment: The `log` parameter of `scatterplot3d` is currently not implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saving the return value from `scatterplot3d` you can use some functions from it to plot points and lines. For example:

```
p3 = scatterplot3d(
                 energy,time,cost,
                 log="xyz", zlab="Cost", ylab="Time", xlab="Energy",
                 highlight.3d = T, angle = 55
)

p3$points3d(x=c(300,300),y=c(25,25),z=c(0,30),type="l",lty=2)
```

[image]

This is documented in the help for `scatterplot3d`:

```
Value:
[...]
points3d: function which draws points or lines into the existing plot.
```

There's also functions for drawing planes and a generic `xyz.convert` function to convert any x,y,z coordinate to a x,y coordinate on the graphics device.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)